# Xcode: Enable Button Based on UITextField Value

Tags: xcode, uibutton, uitextfield

Using two UITextFields and one button. I need to start with the button disabled, but then enable it if the value in the two text fields are within a certain range. Once they are, the button enables and the user may progress.

I've tried using button.isEnabled, but it's not updating properly. Any help?

When searching, I found this post here: http://blog.tarams.com/?p=339 but I've been unable to make it work :(

Comment: Might be useful to actually show some code...

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegate method of UITextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange which is called for each key press, so you can check the fields and enable the button.